# How to install application on websphere dmgr

Tags: websphere

My webspehre server listen on adress: https://some.url.com:9043/ibm/console/ When I want to install application, in virtual host, I can just select default host. But I dont want to install application here. I want to install it on dmgr which listen on the same adress as console. So how it is possible to install application on dmgr ?

Comment: why someone down vote question with no reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I need to find note where dmgr is running:

```
wsadmin>dmgr=AdminControl.completeObjectName("name=dmgr,type=Server,*")
wsadmin>
wsadmin>print dmgr
WebSphere:name=dmgr,process=dmgr,platform=proxy,node=dmgNode...
```

and then install application using wsadmin where virtual host will be default_admin and node will be from previous output

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that Deployment Manager(dmgr) is a separate administrative server which helps in administering the WebSphere server and it is not advisable to mess up with it.

If you want your application to run on specific port then:

1. Login to WebSphere Console.
2. Go to Server --> New Server and then follow the on screen instruction(s) to create the server.
3. Once the server is created, go to Server --> All Server and click on the name of your server.
4. Expand the Ports link and click on details button.
5. On the new screen, modify "WC_defaulthost"(for HTTP) and "WC_defaulthost_secure"(for HTTPS) properties value. Although doing this activity is also not advisable and you should let WebSphere take care of port assignment.

Once these ports are modified you need to map these ports value to the virtual host. You can create the the virtual host as:

1. Go to Environment --> Virtual hosts --> click new.
2. Enter the virtual host name and save the configuration.
3. Click on the virtual host name which you just created and on the new page click on Host Aliases.
4. You need to create 4 entries here for 4 ports for server which you created earlier. You need following 4 ports values : WC_adminhost, WC_defaulthost, WC_adminhost_secure and WC_defaulthost_secure.
5. In host name field, enter ***(star)** and in port enter the port value one by one(mentioned in previous step).

That is it. Now when you deploy the application, map it with the desired virtual host and it should be accessible on it.

Comment: thx man but as you said dmgr is separate server and here I want to install my application not to new server

Answer (score 0):

Applications can run on the DMGR (such as isclite.ear and filetransfer.ear) but the admin console does not allow you you map your app to the deployment manager. You will need to use wsadmin commands AdminApp.install or AdminApp.installinteractive,
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html

Comment: I am already installing application using wsadmin but what arguments should I pass threre to install on dmgr

Comment: especially I dont understand why I need to specify virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install an application on the dmgr, it is for the admin purposes only. Create a new server (JVM) and install it there. The code on the new JVM will then be kept in sync on all environments that have a nodeagent communicating with a dmgr. If somehow you get your code on the dmgr, there is no process to keep that code in sync.